# Can Microsoft Custom Graph Connector retrieve third party data using API calls?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, o365-flow

Question on Microsoft Graph Custom Connector

I do not fully understand the Microsoft Custom Graph connector. I mean I understand it can be used to add third party data sources in the O365 to be accessed via Microsoft Graph. What I don't understand is:
if the data is "sent" from the custom connector to Microsoft Graph in a recurrent mode triggered buy a schedule or event at source OR it can also be called from Microsoft Graph api (I mean does Microsoft Graph expose API calls that via the custom connector retrieve data)? Also, this data (assuming it can be retrieved via api calls) can also be used in Microsoft search? (Or only data pushed from source)

Thank you,
Dr

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Base on Microsoft documentation, it is supposed to do both.  However, as a Graph Connector  user for MS SQL, I don't find this is the case. More on this on the later section...

For instance, all Graph Connectors data are considered External, and they will be provided with Connector ID.  Once you  have this info, then you can go M365 (they rebranded so it's no longer O365) to look up the indexed items.

Now, you can go to Graph Explorer and call the APIs.

About limitation of external item:  I don't find any documentation how the schema is mapped to call Items in Graph Explorer for external items. It's not even clear how the MS indexed the items using the Search and Intelligence at the Admin Center.